# How to add seperate lines to map

Tags: d3.js

On a d3 v4 chart, I have arcs drawn for multiple coordinates. All is well there. Now I would like to draw the lines from a json request. Any new lines would be drawn, whilst existing lines would remain. As I understand, each line would require its own transition....

If I understand correctly, the iteration of coordinates begins at

```
line.attr("d", function(c) {...}
```

Which iterates over each set of coordinates, and then internally groups them so that they are all 'triggered' at the same time, as the one event. Any explanation on this gratefully received.

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Ax4Tby47lFlryzVWCHi2?p=preview

Kev

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  You want each line animation to be staggered?

Comment: Not just staggered, but when new data (coords) become available via an ajax request, the line should be drawn.

Comment: Not enough details.  How will you know when to make the ajax request (when is new data available)? Are you just going to poll your endpoint?

Comment: Yes. The ajax request would be made every N seconds. Any new data (coords) would be drawn on the map.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I'm reading your question correctly, but it sounds like you want your animations to start one after another.  This can be accomplished with a `.delay`:

```
  .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0, 1000") //<-- hide the line
  .transition()
  .delay(function(d, i) { 
    return 5000 * i; //<-- i is the index of the line, so stagger the animation start by index * duration
  })
  .duration(5000)
  .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
    var len = this.getTotalLength();
    return function(t) {
      return (d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0"))(t)
    };
  })
```

---

Full Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <style>

.stroke {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #000;
 stroke-width: 3px;
}
  
.fill{
 fill: #fff;
}


  .graticule {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #777;
    stroke-width: 0.5px;
    stroke-opacity: 0.5;
  }
 
/* the color of land in countries */ 
.land {
 fill: #222;
}

/* the color of borders */
.boundary {
 fill: none;
 stroke: #fff;
 stroke-width: 0.5px;
}
</style>


<svg width="800" height="600"></svg>


<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale((width - 3) / (2 * Math.PI))
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

  var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

  var graticule = d3.geoGraticule();

  svg.append("defs").append("path")
    .datum({
      type: "Sphere"
    })
    .attr("id", "sphere")
    .attr("d", path);

  svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "stroke")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

  svg.append("use")
    .attr("class", "fill")
    .attr("xlink:href", "#sphere");

  svg.append("path")
    .datum(graticule)
    .attr("class", "graticule")
    .attr("d", path);

d3.json("https://rawgit.com/mbostock/topojson/master/examples/world-50m.json", function(error, world) {
 if (error) throw error;
 
 d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/5806b733e4b0bcac9f817223", function(coord){ 

    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.feature(world, world.objects.land))
      .attr("class", "land")
      .attr("d", path);

    svg.insert("path", ".graticule")
      .datum(topojson.mesh(world, world.objects.countries, function(a, b) {
        return a !== b;
      }))
      .attr("class", "boundary")
      .attr("d", path);

    var line = svg.selectAll(".paths")
      .data(coord)
      .enter()
      .append("path");
      
      line.attr("d", function(c) {
        console.log(c);
        var d = {
          source: projection(c.source),
          target: projection(c.destination)
        };
        var dx = d.target[0] - d.source[0],
          dy = d.target[1] - d.source[1],
          dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        return "M" + d.source[0] + "," + d.source[1] + "A" + dr + "," + dr +
          " 0 0,1 " + d.target[0] + "," + d.target[1];
      })
      .style("stroke", "red") // color of the arc line
      .style("stroke-width", 5)
      .style("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", "0, 1000")
      .transition()
      .delay(function(d, i) { 
        return 5000 * i;
      })
      .duration(5000)
      .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", function() {
        var len = this.getTotalLength();
        return function(t) {
          return (d3.interpolateString("0," + len, len + ",0"))(t)
        };
      })
      .on('end', function(d) {
        var c = projection(d.destination);
        svg.append('circle')
          .attr('cx', c[0])
          .attr('cy', c[1])
          .attr('r', 0)
          .style('fill', 'white') // color of the cirle
          .style('fill-opacity', '0.5')
          .transition()
          .duration(2000)
          .attr('r', 50)
          .on('end', function(d) {
            d3.select(this)
              .transition()
              .duration(2000)
              .attr('r', 10);
          });
      });
 });
  });
</script>
  </body>

</html>
```